# Pure CSS sidebar in HTML: Push other elements aside instead of covering them

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I wrote an HTML page with a collapsible sidebar which is `{ position: fixed; left:0 }` when open and `{ left: -285px }` when hidden. The sidebar is on the left and 285px wide, so it's simply outside the viewport when hidden. This approach is based on [a Codepen](https://codepen.io/swastikyadav/pen/zYZPyrN), and there's also [an article](https://dev.to/swastikyadav/menu-sidebar-toggle-functionality-with-pure-css-and-no-javascript-1je6) about it.

Currently, the sidebar (partly) covers the rest of the page in open state. I'd like it to push the other elements to the right instead. Is there a way to achieve this, preferably maintaining my approach to show/hide the sidebar?

Comment: `position: flex` is not a thing.

Comment: You're right, of course: That should have been `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to wrap the rest of the page in a div let's call it `.content` and add the following properties.

```
.content{
  position:relative;
  left:250px;
}
input:checked ~ .content {
  left: 0;
}
```

> Note: This is not a good way to style a sidebar. Try find out another way.